# What's the equivalent of htpasswd in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

I am working on an ASP.NET Core web application.

Please note I am not working with IIS.

The maintenance team, in charge of the server administration does not have access to the application source code.

Is it possible for the maintenance team to add a user/password restriction to access the application ?

It is possible with a php application running on apache server with .htaccess/.htpasswd mechanism. This mechanism is independent of the application.

Is it possible to do the same with a .NET Core Kestrel web server ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Bob5421, by default without IIS in ASP.NET Core, you can use Identity to achieve your requirement.

Comment: Thanks but this need to change application source code …